# Which HTML tags support the name attribute?

Tags: html

Do all HTML tags support the name attribute or are there only a few that one may use the name attribute on? Furthermore, do all tags support the title attribute?

The reason I ask is because I need to store information in these attributes about the current element.
Here is an example:

`<img src="example-image.jpg" alt="Example Image" title="Additional Information" name="Even more info"/>`

`<div class="example-word" title="Information about this tag" name="More information about this tag">Word</div>`

This additional information i am storing in the attribute will be grabbed via javascript.

Comment: You might want to use data-attributes for storing information instead so you don't have to worry about whether it's supported or if it has "reserved" uses.

Comment: No, the name attribute is used for input, select and textarea fields, it is used to give a name to the value of the field when it's submitted. As Juhana said use data-attributes for unique data storage on DOM elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.name) `name` officially only applies to the following elements: `<a>, <applet>, <button>, <form>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <map>, <meta>, <object>, <param>, <select>, and <textarea>` - basically form fields, links, and plugin objects.

If you want to store other information (metadata) with an element, you should look at [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes. This is the recommended approach for HTML5, but will work on older browsers too. This also means you can store as many different pieces of extra data as you need

```
<img src="example-image.jpg" alt="Example Image" title="Additional Information"
    data-name="Even more info" data-other-info="Some other information" />

<div class="example-word" title="Information about this tag"
    data-name="More information about this tag">Word</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own tags and read them via javascript. These tags have to begin with `data-`:

```
<div data-whatever="Information the world needs"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tags don’t “support” anything. HTML specifications define which attributes are valid for which elements. For the `name` attribute as well as the `title` attribute, this depends on HTML version.

Browsers don’t care that much about specs. If your markup contains the attribute `foo=bar`, they happily include `foo` in the `attributes` property of the element node. They may or may not also make `foo` a property of the node itself. For `title`, this happens, i.e. “modern browsers support `title` for all elements”, and this also means that most browsers implement that attribute as a “tooltip”, which is a usability nightmare, but I digress. For `name`, this happens for some elements but not all, and for controls inside a form, that attribute *also* has a specialized meaning (it affects the issue whether the value of the control is included in the form data).

The recommended way to store data is to use `data-*` attributes, since they are guaranteed to have no meaning and no effect, beyond what you specify in your scripts or style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You really should store it using the `data-` attribute, but you can always use `name` and access it like so:

```
obj.getAttribute('name'); //Pure JavaScript
$(obj).attr('name'); //jQuery
```

But really, stick to `data-`.