# How can i do scroll to specific div on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this html codes:

```
<span name="value1"></span>
<span name="value2"></span>
```

I'm trying to make the page scroll to these sections every time the page's URL with the span loads.

`Example: htttp://site.com/index.html#value1`

If `value1` is selected, there is a scroll when the page is opened.

I'm trying this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        var target = $(this.hash);  
        if (target.length == 0) target = $('[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');  
        if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');  
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 700);  
        return false;  
});
```

I can do this with `id` but I want to do it with name attr.

Comment: You can use a mixture of [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and  [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). Select the element by attribute value then scroll to it. `document.querySelector("span[name='value1']").scrollIntoView()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor

Can be adapted to your needs I think. There are even up-to-date solutions without jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

May I kindly suggest to consider a solution without JavaScript?

```
<a name="value1"></a><span name="value1"></span>
```

This will use the browser's default behavior to go to the respective section upon loading the page.

---

Should the identification of the element be the issue, you may try traditional JS:

```
if (target.length == 0) {
    target = document.getElementsByName(window.location.hash.substr(1))[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code looks like it should work for both `id` and `name` attributes, and since it works for ids, I think maybe the problem is one of two possible issues in your HTML:

#### 1. When you're trying to scroll to an element by `name`, do you also have an element with that `id` on the page?

As you can see from these lines in your code:

```js
var target = $(this.hash);  
if (target.length == 0) target = $('[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
```

The script will only look for an element with `name={hash}` if an element with `id={hash}` is not found.

#### 2. Your  tags are invalid HTML

I don't think this technically should prevent the script from working the way you want, but it's probably useful to know anyway. Only certain elements are supposed to have a `name` attribute, as you can see from this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724898/which-html-tags-support-the-name-attribute).

I believe what you want here is `<a name="value...">`, using the Anchor tag for one of its [original intended uses](http://freepages.rootsweb.com/%7Epasher/computers/anchors.htm).